# SD card reader not working on Elementary OS

Tags: elementary-os, realtek

I have a Lenovo S210 with a Realtek card reader installed (rts5139), but it does not work. I have tried restarting Elementary while I have an SD card inside, but I am unable to view the SD card contents.

When I run **dmesg** in terminal, I get the following pertaining to the rts5139:

```
[    8.802265] rts5139: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned. [    8.803732] Initializing rts5139 USB card reader driver...
  [    8.810760] scsi6 : SCSI emulation for RTS5139 USB card reader
  [    8.811011] usbcore: registered new interface driver rts5139
  [    8.811015] Realtek rts5139 USB card reader support registered.
  [    8.811027] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- xD/SD/M.S.       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
  [    8.811643] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
  [    8.877009] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

When I run **sudo lshw**, I get this:

```
 *-scsi           physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@3:4
            logical name: scsi6
            capabilities: emulated scsi-host
            configuration: driver=rts5139
          *-disk
               description: SCSI Disk
               product: xD/SD/M.S.
               vendor: Generic-
               physical id: 0.0.0
               bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
               logical name: /dev/sdb
               version: 1.00
               serial: 3
               capabilities: removable
             *-medium
                  physical id: 0
                  logical name: /dev/sdb
```

**lsmod | grep rts5139**, brings up:

```
​rts5139               351188  0
```

From my limited knowledge and research online, it seems that this driver has been an issue with anything running kernel 12.04 along with a few older distros. However, due to Elementary not being fully supported with a newer kernel, I was wondering if there was a way to possibly just upgrade the one driver.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you positive sure the kernel is the issue? You can easily upgrade it if you think that would solve it.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure. I can just go by what multiple Google searches have brought up. This link is about the issue in Ubuntu, but it seems to be based on the same kernel issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1176709 I know the upgrade seems easy, but Elementary isn't full supported on newer kernels.